# Django Create Object

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Is that possible creating object when we create another object via `models.py` or `forms.py`?

models.py

```
class Study(models.Model):
    nameS= models.CharField(max_length=40)
def __init__(self):
    System.create(Study=self)

class System(models.Model):
    Name= models.TextField(max_length=25)
    Study= models.OneToOneField(Study)
```

Comment: Well, that would create a new System every time you *instantiate* a Test object, which includes fetching an existing one from the database, which isn't presumably what you want. But I don't think I understand what you do actually want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it should create the System object only once, during Test object creation:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    nameS= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk: # the object doesn't have PK until the very first save
            super(Test, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            Test2.objects.create(test=self)
        else:
            super(Test, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You may need to populate `field1` field too, because it cannot be NULL according to your current setup.

Comment: I'm sorry, I saw a mistake in my code, it's okay now, (it wasn't "System.create(Study=self)" but "Test2.create(Study=self)"
And okay i'm gonna try you're code

Comment: Edited my answer. But it's not the most important part. The idea of save method overriding is something you need to grasp very early during django learning process.

Comment: I have an error, "'study' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

Comment: Ok tks it works !
I just changed this line : System.objects.create(Study=self.pk) by System.objects.create(Study=self)

Comment: Yep, you're right. Also consider giving your fields lowercased names. In general don't wander off from the good practice schemes. They were formulated for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pre_save` signal:

```
# models.py
from django.db.models import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Study)
def system_creator(**kwargs):
    created = kwargs.get('created')
    # flag `True` if object created now
    if created:
        study = kwargs.get('instance')
        test = Test.objects.create(Study=study,...)
```